# How are Jersey @Consumes endpoints matched?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am designing a RESTful endpoint to receive files. I would like to it to accept POSTing as both plain file/stream and multipart. Is there a rule how are endpoints matched by the servlet container? Would the code below work reliably, or is this implementation specific? Can I get away with WILDCARD, or do I have to limit this to APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM?

```
@Path("foo")
public class Foo {
    @POST
    @Path("{filename}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public Response uploadFileDirect(
        @PathParam("filename") String filename,
        InputStream is)
    {
        // process input stream
        Response.ok().build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("{filename}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFileMultipart(
        @PathParam("filename") String filename,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream is)
    {
        // process input stream
        Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think better to remove the WILDCARD is good.because no such sentence.https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart

Comment: @user1419950 I am not sure I understand. The first endpoint is not multipart, only second one is. Also WILDCARD exists http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified in the [JAX-RS spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) 3.7.2 Request Matching

> [...]
>
> Resource class/object is found and all resource and sub resource methods are put into set *`M`*
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Identify the method that will handle the request: 
>      
>    a.  Filter *`M`* by removing members that do not meet the following criteria: 
>      
>        [...] 
>      
>    b. Sort *`M`* in descending order as follows:
>      
>        * The primary key is the media type of input data. Methods whose `@Consumes` value is the best match for the media type of the request are sorted first. 
>      
>        * The secondary key is the `@Produces` value. Methods whose value of `@Produces` best matches the value of the request accept header are sorted first.
>
> Determining the best matching media types follows the general rule: `n/m` > `n/*` > `*/*`, i.e. a method that explicitly consumes the request media type or produces one of the requested media types is sorted before a method that consumes or produces `*/*`.

If you look at the last paragraph (that determines the best matching), it says that `*/*` (`MediaType.WILDCARD`) is given the least priority. More specific media types will always win.